# Eclipse Breakpoint and get Environment Variables

Tags: java, eclipse

This is a pretty trivial question but when coding in C# in Visual Studio I can easily put a breakpoint at any point in my code and then under the "Locals" area I can see the value of any currently initialized variables.

When I'm coding in Java in Eclipse though and I click on the sidebar, a blue dot appears (and when hovering over it - it says it is a breakpoint) however when running my code the breakpoint seems to be ignored. The code keeps running.

How can I get my code to stop at the breakpoint and how can I view the currently initialized variables?

Comment: that is the correct way of setting a breakpoint, so maybe you are not entering the code

Comment: Hope you have not disabled breaking on breakpoints. Check if you have pressed the button with blue dot crossed.

Comment: Are you running in "run" mode or "debug" mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You application should run in a debug mode. There is a Expression window where you can play with the object in debug mode.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html